Setting pageHeight for a large Detail band
My JasperReport has the following dimensions.
jasperReport - pageHeight 3500
title band - height 260
detail band - height 3000
The detail band contains multiple tables and charts and NO sub reports. I use break between these tables and charts so that I get 3 pages. Now I need to set the pageHeight to 802 from 3500 to avoid vast blank space in each page, but the detail band height is 3000. Please suggest what to do.

A better approach to a tall detail band with break elements is to create multiple smaller detail bands, one for each table and chart.
In Jaspersoft Studio you can create multiple detail bands by right clicking one of the bands in the Outline view and doing Add Detail Band.

